# How to order documents by timestamp automatically in firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, dart, timestamp

I've created an app and I am using firebase as well but I want to order the documents by timestamp such that my documents will be ordered from recently added ones to older ones.

I wonder if there is a solution rather than using orderBy method because my project is very big.

please help me.

Note: I am devolping the app using flutter & dart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firebase Realtime Database always returns results in ascending order. There is no way to order descending order.

This means you have two common options:

1. Reverse the nodes on the client.
2. Store an inverted value in a property, and order on that.

If you want to retrieve a subset of the items, keep in mind that you can combine any of these approaches with `limitToFirst()` and `limitToLast`. For example, to get the 10 most recent messages, you could:

1. order on timestamp
2. get the last 10 items
3. reverse them client-side

Also see:

- [How to get data from firebase in descending order of value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45137899/how-to-get-data-from-firebase-in-descending-order-of-value), which shows an example of storing an inverted score.
- [Sorting in descending order in Firebase database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45357920/sorting-in-descending-order-in-firebase-database), which shows someone using the `limitToLast` approach mentioned above.
- [Display posts in descending posted order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25611356/display-posts-in-descending-posted-order), which shows how to invert a date value. Please ignore the use of priorities, as you'd nowadays just store the inverted value in a regular property and use `orderByChild()`.
- Many more links from [this list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44443042).

Comment: I did as you have mentioned above and I've created a field called time and it is equal to DateTime.now() (Dart) but it orders according to the current time of the users so this makes a disturbance in my app especially in chats

Comment: That sounds like a new problem problem to me. But if you want to have a consistent timestamp that is not dependent on the client-side click, use [`ServerValue.timestamp`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_database/latest/firebase_database/ServerValue/timestamp-constant.html). Read more about it in the documentation here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#server-timestamps