# How to output the firebase snapshot in reverse order?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get the latest 3 data from the database and display them in reverse order in the HTML page.

Code:

```
var refForevent = database.ref('/events/post');

refForevent.orderByChild("intro").limitToLast(3).on('child_added', function(snapshot){
    
    var eventlist = []

    eventlist.push(snapshot)
    console.log(eventlist)

    eventlist.reverse()
            
    document.getElementById("event1date").innerHTML = moment(eventlist[0].intro).format("MMM Do YYYY");
    document.getElementById("event1title").innerHTML = eventlist[0].title;

    document.getElementById("event2date").innerHTML = moment(eventlist[1].intro).format("MMM Do YYYY");
    document.getElementById("event2title").innerHTML = eventlist[1].title;

    document.getElementById("event3date").innerHTML = moment(eventlist[1].intro).format("MMM Do YYYY");
    document.getElementById("event3title").innerHTML = eventlist[1].title;
    
})
```

Output: [Output that I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfAga.png)

Database: [image: Database]

Comment: UPDATE: I'm sorry. It is orderByChild("intro"). I forgot to update it before posting it here. My bad.

Comment: There's an `edit` link right under your question so that you make edits like that to your question.

Answer (score 1):

I see that the field `intro` contains a date.

Here is one solution:

1. Take the value of this field
2. Remove the hyphen separators (e.g. from 2020-12-10 you get the number 20201210)
3. Multiply this number by -1
4. Store the resulting value in another field
5. Sort on this field

Alternatively (and more elegant...), use the date to create a Timestamp, multiply it by -1 and use it as explained above, i.e. store the resulting value in another field and sort on this field.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're listening to the `child_added` event, your function gets called with each post node that matches the query in the order in which Firebase returns them. So your `eventlist` will only ever contain one node at a time.

To reverse the items, you can either get Firebase to return the values in reverse order, as Renaud suggest (I'll also link some answers below), or you can listen to all results in once go and then reversing client-side (as your code already seem to be trying). The latter would look something like:

```
var refForevent = database.ref('/events/post');

refForevent.orderByChild("date").limitToLast(3).on('value', function(results){
    
    var eventlist = []
    results.forEach(function(snapshot) {
        eventlist.push(snapshot.val())
    });

    eventlist.reverse()
    console.log(eventlist);
            
    ...    
})
```

So this:

- Listens to the `value` event, instead of `child_added`, so that it gets all matching child nodes in one go.
- If then loops over the results, adding them to the array,
- It calls `.val()` on each child snapshot, to get the value from it.

For more on descending sorting, also see:

- [Display posts in descending posted order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25611356/display-posts-in-descending-posted-order) (the oldest I could find describing the trick with negative values)
- [firebase -> date order reverse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44442816/firebase-date-order-reverse) (with many more links from there)
- [Sorting in descending order in Firebase database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45357920/sorting-in-descending-order-in-firebase-database)

Comment: This worked for the first event and it was in the order I wanted it too. But I got an error "Cannot set innerHTML of null" for the rest.

Comment: That error seems unrelated to the Firebase interaction, which is what I helped with here. For the best help on Stack Overflow, isolate the problem as much as possible as shown in [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Okay. Thank you :)